# how to plot two-dimension array in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have dataset with

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]].
```

and call

```
plot(data)
plot.show()
```

then y-axis is treated as inner array's value.

what I want is

```
f(0,0) = 1, f(0,1) = 2, f(1,2) = 3, 
f(1,0) = 4, f(1,1) = 5, f(1,2) = 6,
f(2,0) = 7, f(2,1) = 8, f(2,2) = 9
```

The question is, how to change y-axis to array's index instead of array's value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

1) Python does not have the 2D, `f[i,j]`, index notation, but to get that you can use numpy.  Picking a arbitrary index pair from your example:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.array(data)
print f[1,2]
# 6
print data[1][2] 
# 6
```

2) Then for the plot you can do:

```
plt.imshow(f, interpolation="nearest", origin="upper")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

So here you have representative colors where you have the numbers in your `f` array.

Here I specified `origin="upper"`.  Usually people want the `(0,0)` point at the bottom for a data array (as opposed to an image), but you write out your array with `(0,0)` in the upper left, which is what `"upper"` does.  This is also the default, btw, but it's explicit use might make clear that there's an option.

Answer (score -1):

What module do you use for plotting? Matplotlib?

What you want is a 2d Histogram.
There are various implementations. I recommend the one which comes with numpy
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html

Comment: I don't think he want's a 2d histogram.  Plotting a 2d array is done through `imshow`